# Estourando erro net.vidageek.mirror.exception.ReflectionProviderException: Could not invoke method, como corrigir?

Tags: java, java-ee, vraptor

Estou em um código onde no momento que executo esse método em java do HtmlUnit:

```java
// SIMULANDO UM NAVEGADOR
WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.getDefault());

client.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
client.setCookiesEnabled(true);

System.out.println("Criando o HtmlPage");

// OBTENDO A PÁGINA
HtmlPage htmlPage = (HtmlPage) client
    .getPage("http://www.meusiteficticio.com/");// onde ocorre o erro;
```

Ocorre a Exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: net.vidageek.mirror.exception.ReflectionProviderException: Could not invoke method autenticar
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:120)
```

Como podem ver utilizo o VRaptor, e também estou usando o hibernate, e quando faço os testes pelo TestNG, roda normal, e me traz essa htmlPage.

O que poderia ser, sendo que está dentro de um método que tem o `throws Exception`, e estou tratando o erro se ocorrer com o `throw new Exception("erro");`.

Obs: o link (http://www.meusiteficticio.com/) foi usado para preservar o site do cliente.

*Stacktrace* ficou assim:

```
type Exception report

message net.vidageek.mirror.exception.ReflectionProviderException: Could not invoke method autenticar

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: net.vidageek.mirror.exception.ReflectionProviderException: Could not invoke method autenticar
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:120)
root cause

net.vidageek.mirror.exception.ReflectionProviderException: Could not invoke method autenticar
    net.vidageek.mirror.provider.java.PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.invoke(PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.java:45)
    net.vidageek.mirror.invoke.MethodHandlerByMethod.withArgs(MethodHandlerByMethod.java:54)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.ExecuteMethod.execute(ExecuteMethod.java:87)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:266)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:253)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:232)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:169)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:165)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:119)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:112)
    org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:83)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:78)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.java:75)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:58)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.next(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.next(DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.java:49)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.next(Unknown Source)
    cw.assist.intercept.AcessoIntercept.intercepta(AcessoIntercept.java:195)
    cw.assist.intercept.AcessoIntercept$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercepta(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    net.vidageek.mirror.provider.java.PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.invoke(PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.java:38)
    net.vidageek.mirror.invoke.MethodHandlerByMethod.withArgs(MethodHandlerByMethod.java:54)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker.invokeMethod(StepInvoker.java:63)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker.tryToInvoke(StepInvoker.java:54)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.tryToInvoke(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor.executeAround(InterceptorExecutor.java:75)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.executeAround(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.execute(AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.java:87)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor.intercept(FlashInterceptor.java:98)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:58)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.start(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:93)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.start(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.RequestHandlerObserver.handle(RequestHandlerObserver.java:86)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:266)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:253)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:232)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:169)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:165)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:119)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:112)
    org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:83)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:116)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jaxen/JaxenException
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:237)
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:116)
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:89)
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:450)
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:359)
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:407)
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:395)
    cw.assist.redcap.RedCapApi.chkAutenticacao(RedCapApi.java:307)
    cw.assist.controller.LoginController.autenticar(LoginController.java:56)
    cw.assist.controller.LoginController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.autenticar(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    net.vidageek.mirror.provider.java.PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.invoke(PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.java:38)
    net.vidageek.mirror.invoke.MethodHandlerByMethod.withArgs(MethodHandlerByMethod.java:54)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.ExecuteMethod.execute(ExecuteMethod.java:87)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:266)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:253)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:232)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:169)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:165)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:119)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:112)
    org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:83)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:78)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.java:75)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:58)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.next(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.next(DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.java:49)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.next(Unknown Source)
    cw.assist.intercept.AcessoIntercept.intercepta(AcessoIntercept.java:195)
    cw.assist.intercept.AcessoIntercept$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercepta(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    net.vidageek.mirror.provider.java.PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.invoke(PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.java:38)
    net.vidageek.mirror.invoke.MethodHandlerByMethod.withArgs(MethodHandlerByMethod.java:54)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker.invokeMethod(StepInvoker.java:63)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker.tryToInvoke(StepInvoker.java:54)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.tryToInvoke(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor.executeAround(InterceptorExecutor.java:75)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.executeAround(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.execute(AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.java:87)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor.intercept(FlashInterceptor.java:98)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:58)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.start(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:93)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.start(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.RequestHandlerObserver.handle(RequestHandlerObserver.java:86)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:266)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:253)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:232)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:169)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:165)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:119)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:112)
    org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:83)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:116)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jaxen.JaxenException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:237)
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:116)
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:89)
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:450)
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:359)
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:407)
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:395)
    cw.assist.redcap.RedCapApi.chkAutenticacao(RedCapApi.java:307)
    cw.assist.controller.LoginController.autenticar(LoginController.java:56)
    cw.assist.controller.LoginController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.autenticar(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    net.vidageek.mirror.provider.java.PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.invoke(PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.java:38)
    net.vidageek.mirror.invoke.MethodHandlerByMethod.withArgs(MethodHandlerByMethod.java:54)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.ExecuteMethod.execute(ExecuteMethod.java:87)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:266)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:253)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:232)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:169)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:165)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:119)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:112)
    org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:83)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:78)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.java:75)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:58)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.next(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.next(DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.java:49)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.next(Unknown Source)
    cw.assist.intercept.AcessoIntercept.intercepta(AcessoIntercept.java:195)
    cw.assist.intercept.AcessoIntercept$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercepta(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    net.vidageek.mirror.provider.java.PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.invoke(PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.java:38)
    net.vidageek.mirror.invoke.MethodHandlerByMethod.withArgs(MethodHandlerByMethod.java:54)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker.invokeMethod(StepInvoker.java:63)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker.tryToInvoke(StepInvoker.java:54)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.tryToInvoke(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor.executeAround(InterceptorExecutor.java:75)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.executeAround(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.execute(AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.java:87)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor.intercept(FlashInterceptor.java:98)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:58)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.start(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:93)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.start(Unknown Source)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.RequestHandlerObserver.handle(RequestHandlerObserver.java:86)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:266)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:253)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:232)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:169)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:165)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:119)
    org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:112)
    org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:83)
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:116)
```

Comment: Tem como incluir todo *stack trace*? Outra coisa, tu tem o *controller* para incluir também?

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jaxen.JaxenException` e `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jaxen/JaxenException`. Veja se não está indo para o classpath versão errada/conflitante de `dom4j` e/ou `jaxen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta incluir o jar do [Jaxen](http://jaxen.org/releases.html) no server lib do [Wildfly](http://wildfly.org/)(wildfly/x.x.x/standalone/lib/ext)